# Does Ember need a route to be generated for every screen

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am having the following scenario;

There are multiple workflows. Take workflow1
It is a 3-step workflow with user input form on Step 1. So I have created a route for this /workflow1/step1

Now on this step1 form, I have a field (lookup value) & button next to it, on click of which, I need to show a new screen (this would entirely replace step1 screen). On this screen is again a form (kind of filter) and user can filter based on this lookup form and select any data.

The selected user data would populate the value in the step1 "lookup" field.

No my questions are, what is the best way to implement this lookup screen.

1. Do I have to create a new route (say /lookup) i.e. at root level and implement it ?
2. This lookup screen is going to get called from multiple places (say from workflow2, workflow3) and it's behavior is going to be identical in all cases. Only difference being it's selected value is going to the step1 of the calling workflow. (i.e. it can be /workflow1/step1 OR /workflow2/step1)
3. Is there any way in Ember, by which I can implement such kind of screens, without necessarily having to generate a separate route for it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Route for this, but for me it looks more like a *modal* form.
I would create a lookup component, and then use a boolean to toggle the visibility of this component. A Full sized white background to cover everything else. simple.

Just remember that the rest of the DOM is still rendered.

You still can create a Route if you want to change the url. Also definitely not a bad solution!

You could also create a component route, use the component name as dynamic segment and call the component with the `component` helper. So many options!

Comment: Thanks for all the options! Couple of questions;
1 . Since step1 is a user-input form, if I use a new route & navigate to it and then come back, how can I persist the earlier user-entered values in step1 
2. For the 3rd solution, how do I use component name as dynamic segment ? Any examples if u could list that would be really great.

Comment: Well, 1: Use a model to save your data. Since you live-bind the user input you just need to persist the model. Remember: controllers are singletons and can hold state! Or give the model forward and back.
2: Use the `component` helper. So `{{component componentName}}`like [here](https://ember-twiddle.com/e20cf37c2425a68e7edc?openFiles=cmp.template.hbs%2Ccmp.route.js)

Answer (score -1):

To me, your scenario looks to be of `nested routes`.

Ember provides full support for nested routes when you want to show a template within another template. In your case:

1.Create a route at root level which will be your workflow route.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('workflow', { path: '/workflow' });
});
```

On this you can put your template for step1.

2.Create a nested route for lookup which will be nested inside `workflow` route.

```
  Router.map(function() {
    this.route('workflow', { path: '/workflow' }, function(){
      this.route('lookup',{ path: '/lookup' });
    });
  });
```

if you want to have workflows like `w1`, `w2` and `w3`, then you can create routes for them and use `rendertemplate` function to render same `lookout` in all.

```
App.w1Route = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render('lookout');
  }
});
```

Similarly you can create other two workflows with same lookout template.

Comment: 2 questions;
1. lookup is common, but called from diff places/workflows. So can this handle /workflow1/lookup , /workflow2/lookup, /workflow3/lookup ,etc
2. Is creating a new route the only way to handle for the new 'lookup' screen ?

Comment: ans 1: we can access nested routes from anywhere.
ans2: since we can access nested routes from anywhere so no need to create a separate route for it.

Comment: In your example, you are using nested routes, but this would also require the use of dynamic segments. so can you show the example with multiple workflows (w1, w2, w3) and each having common lookup under them